# Compile GWT project with GWT project dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, ant, compilation

I'd love to ask about my issue with ant script. I have two GWT projects and one depends on the other. I'm trying to compile them with ant script, but I'm failing due to:

```
 [java]       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/$PATH/$CLASS_NAME.java'
 [java]          [ERROR] Line 29: No source code is available for type $INHERITED_INTERFACE; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

while $INERITED_INTERFACE is from the library the compiled project depends on and $CLASS_NAME is a class that implements the interface.

I tried it simple, but it's not working:

```
<target name="gwtcomp" depends="javacomp" description="GWT to JS">
    <echo message="Building GWT" />

    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/src" />
            <path refid="project.class.path" />
        </classpath>
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx512M" />
        <arg value="-strict" />

        <arg value="${project.dep.gwt.config}" />
        <arg value="${project.gwt.config}" />
    </java>
</target>
```

but it can't go pass the errors. I've also inherited the GWT library with:

```
<module rename-to='project'>
    ...
    <inherits name='my.lib.common.Common'/>
</module>
```

Not really sure what's wrong. Common.gwt.xml is there and it points client and shared as source packages. Could anyone help with that?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to add the location for the sources of your `my.lib.common.Common` library to your classpath in your ant script. 
Something like this:

```
<classpath>
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/src" />
    <path refid="project.class.path" />
    <pathelement location="LOCATION_TO_MY.LIB.COMMON.COMMON"/>
</classpath>
```